# Can we 'dope' a fluid to make it become a superfluid?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, cold-atoms

The only element that can become a superfluid is Helium (He-3 and He-4) since it does not solidify not matter how cold it gets, hence it can reach the superfluid transition temperature whilst still a liquid.

Can we make an artificial mixture of elements such that this new material could also reach the superfluid transition temperature while still a liquid? In the same way as we dope semiconductors, can we 'dope' a fluid that would not normally not become a superfluid for it to exhibit such a phase transition?

Comment: It seems that neutron matter can be a superfluid, too. Technically neutrons can be considered isotopes with charge zero, so neutron matter would actually lead the periodic table before hydrogen. There are also suggestions that metallic hydrogen may have a superfluid phase next to its superconducting phase. But I am getting pedantic, am I not? :-)

Comment: "seems"? Theoretically or experimentally? What about other, heavier, elements?

Comment: @SuperCiocia https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732662/226902 : theoretically expected superfluid neutrons and superconducting protons (very indirect evidence of neutron superfluidity is given by the rapid cooling of CasA and pulsar glitches).